# Fun with synonyms - "evaluation/investigation/etc."

Tags: usage, vocabulary, nuances, synonyms

Explain the differences in the following vocabulary.  They all essentially mean some form of investigation, inspection, etc.  Please don't just write the definitions; I'm lost on how they differ, when to use one over others, what they apply to, and so on.  After much study, a lot of them still seem to overlap in my mind (and maybe they do).  Here they are.  Good luck!

1. 監査【かんさ】
2. 鑑査【かんさ】
3. 検査【けんさ】
4. 検討【けんとう】
5. 審査【しんさ】
6. 捜査【そうさ】
7. 探査【たんさ】
8. 調査【ちょうさ】
9. 査察【ささつ】
10. 視察【しさつ】
11. 監察【かんさつ】

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a few I can tell without hesitation.
I'd see ALC to get example sentences for the others…

1. 検査【けんさ】 -> The nuclear safety agency *inspected* the people from Fukusima as well as their luggage.
2. 検討【けんとう】 -> We *consider* adding another wheel to our latest unicycle.
3. 審査【しんさ】-> The pre-doctoral *examination* will be held in December
4. 探査【たんさ】
5. 調査【ちょうさ】 -> There has been a *poll* to see how many people liked nattô on toasts.
6. 監察【かんさつ】-> We *observed* a color change when adding marmelade to coke.

Comment: 探査 is used in 宇宙探査機, "spacecraft". It's used to mean "explore" or "probe" most often.

Comment: [[ We consider adding another wheel to our latest unicycle. ]] -- Haha, what the heck kind of sentence is that???  ;)