# What is the difference between 検事 and 検察官?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I found the same translation for **検察官** and **検事** : "public prosecutor". But I guess there is a reason for the two words to exist. Is one of them more formal ?

Comment: Somewhat related:  [Fun with synonyms - “evaluation/investigation/etc.”](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2625/78)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

検察官 is "public prosecutor". 検事 is the name of a position of a public prosecutor. Their job descriptions are 「検事総長」,「次長検事」,「検事長」,「検事」,「副検事」sort by highest in rank to lowest.

Source: http://www.kensatsu.go.jp/gyoumu/kensatsukan.htm
 http://careergarden.jp/kensatsujimukan/kenji-jimukan-chigai/

Comment: I don't understand, could you elaborate ?

Comment: @blaoi 検事 is a one's job description. We call the highest rank in Japanese public prosecutors 検事総長.

Comment: A 検察官 is a "public official" (官) working at a 検察庁 which is the "bureau" (庁) responsible for "prosecution" (検察). 検事 is the name of one of the jobs, or positions that a 検察官 might occupy. Sort of like a police officer works at a police station, but his specific job or position might be as a detective, sergeant etc.